# The day before/ yesterday...were/had been -- forming sentences, trying to convey things concerning the past and the past before past

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

We were all afraid thinking what might happen to us. What increased the fear was how it had been in the paper **yesterday/the day before**.. that the killer had killed all the people that **were/had been** there at the party.

In the first case, can I use the day before instead of yesterday ?
And in the second case, can I use had been instead of were? What difference does it make whether I use had been or were?

Comment: You *should* use "the day before" unless *we were all afraid* refers to earlier today. And perfect isn't obligatory in the relative clause; for that matter, neither is the verb. " .... had killed everybody at the party."

Comment: @StoneyB, so basically, once I've established i'm talking about the past before past, I don't need to keep using the had, right?

Comment: Check this:  [4. When and how should I use the perfect?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13262/32).

Comment: @StoneyB, I've seen that answer before.

Answer (score 1):

> We were all afraid thinking what might happen to us.

since your sentence is placed in the past, it would be better to use

> We were all afraid thinking what might have happened to us.

placing both your "fear" and the hypothetical consequences at the same time as the killing.

> how it had been in the paper yesterday
>   how it had been in the paper the day before

are equivalent, however

> the previous day

might be a clearer choice since "the day before" is usually part of a construction like
"the day before yesterday".

> what it said in the paper yesterday

is more idiomatic.

> people that *were* at the party
>   people that *had been* at the party

are equivalent and can be interchanged without loss of understanding in your example.

> We were all afraid thinking what *might have happened* to us.  What increased *our* fear was how it had been *reported* in the paper the day before... that the killer had killed all the people that were at the party.

is a correct sentence.

Comment: And is the entire thing grammatically correct?

Comment: "We were all afraid thinking what might happen to us."  Indicates at some point in the past you (plural) were afraid (at that time).

"We were all afraid thinking what might have happened to us."  Indicates that at a point after the event occurred you (plural) were afraid when considering the event in retrospect (at a time other than the event).  I'm not sure the OP means the later.

Comment: Since we know the article in the paper refers to a previous event, you can finish the final sentence, "...all the people at the party", no need for "that were" or "had been".